# Create new site from dropdown with webtemplates

Tags: site-collection, silverlight

I am newbee Sharepoint developer, so forgive me if this is a silly question. I want to create subsites on a sitecollection. I have by code limited the available webtemplates for the subsites to two different templates (will be more later on). I can access those templates if I go to "Site Actions" -> "New Site". But I would also like to have those templates populate a dropdown-list on the site, so that the user can choose a template and press a "Create new site"-button. When they press that button I would like them to end up in the Silverlight control "Create new site" with choosen webtemplate, and the "More options" selected. Apparently I do not have enough "points" to add a snapshot of where I want the user to end up.

My question is how I open the "New site" "popup", when the user has choosen a webtemplate and clicked "Create a new site". I hope my question makes any sense.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. I know that this is a Silverlight control, and that I do not have access to change the Silverlight code, but I just want to do a modified version of the event that happens when I press "Site Actions" -> "New Site". I want to do the same, with only difference that I want to limit available webtemplates to the choosen one, AND go directly to "More options". Is this a javascript thing?

My setting is Windows Server 2008 R2 and Sharepoint Server 2010 stand alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a site using [WebCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.webcollection.add.aspx) part of the [WebCreationInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.webcreationinformation.aspx) is the [WebTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.webcreationinformation.webtemplate.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Per! I will look into it. Just so that I understand it correctly, it is possible to use the above methods to create new sitecollection with choosen webtemplate?

Comment: No, not site collections only sites. The Client Side Object Model can't do anything outside the current Site Collection, so there is no way to create Site Collections.